# Disable Litespeed optimisation for posts

Tags: wordpress, caching, litespeed

I have a weird request. I want to turn off litespeed optimisation for posts. I wanted to exclude those urls from litespeed plugin from optimising it. I tried excluding those urls, using the `URI Excludes` option in Tuning, and also with the `Exclude Settings` option under Cache option. Still no use. But when I disable the litespeed cache plugin, the js files are working. So I thought why not just disable litespeed cache from working on posts. Is there a way to do it?